# PHP Triples DES CBC/192bit decrypt

Tags: c#, php, encryption, soap

I'm trying to complete a SOAP authentication proces but I can't get the encryption/descyption of the secrets to work. The SOAP service is build with .NET, I try to integrate the service in PHP.

Examples for the service are supplied in C# syntax but I need to get this "translated" to PHP syntax.

Example of the data I receive to work with:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [TicketGrantingTicketResponse] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Status] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Code] => Success
                )

            [TicketGrantingTicket] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Token] => 0187cde6cae1416a9a903065fef2ffeb
                    [Secret] => d724P3/dPHutvEfiPMX1dQ==
                    [Timestamp] => 2013-02-20T09:00:45
                    [Expires] => 2013-02-20T09:01:45
                )

        )

)
```

The C# example code (decryption only to start with ;))

```
// save the token for later use
this.tgtToken = rs.TicketGrantingTicket.Token;

// extract the secret from response
string secret = rs.TicketGrantingTicket.Secret;

// Now the decoding/decryption of the secret will have to be performed
// First we get the plain encoded bytes by converting the BASE64 secret
byte[] decodedSecret = Convert.FromBase64String(secret);

// Second, we create an MD5 hash of our passphrase which will serve as 
// base data for the decryption.
// Note that in C# the md5 hash creation requires a byte array as input.
// The pass phrase is required to be a UTF8-encoded string, so we use
// the UTF8 encoding to convert to plain bytes.
MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] md5PassPhraseHash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(opPassPhrase));

// Now we have to prepare the TripleDES decryption. TripleDES requires us
// to pass a key and initialization vector. We use the 128bit md5 hash as key.
// The initialization vector is created with the leading 8 bytes (first 64bit)
// from the md5 hash.
byte[] cKey = md5PassPhraseHash;
byte[] cIV = new byte[8];
Array.Copy(cKey, cIV, 8);

// Decrypt with TripleDES
TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
tdes.Key = cKey;
tdes.IV = cIV;

byte[] decryptedSecret = null;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) 
{
    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, tdes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)) 
    {
        cs.Write(decodedSecret, 0, decodedSecret.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        cs.Close();
    }

    decryptedSecret = ms.ToArray();
}

    // finally convert the decrypted bytes back to a UTF8 encoded string
    string decryptedResult = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedSecret);
```

I got this for now in PHP, but I'm just not sure I'm walking the right path:

```
            // Get token.
            $sToken = $oTicketGrantingTicketResponse->TicketGrantingTicketResponse->TicketGrantingTicket->Token;

            // Get secret.
            $sSecret = $oTicketGrantingTicketResponse->TicketGrantingTicketResponse->TicketGrantingTicket->Secret;

            // Get BASE64 decoded secret.
            $sSecretDecoded = base64_decode($sSecret);

            // Create MD5 hash of passphrase (just an example passphrase).
            $sPassPhraseHash = md5('sj93fhdsfd', true);

            // Decode secret with 3DES(CBC/192bit) using the MD5 passphrase.
            $sSecretDecoded = @mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $sPassphraseMD5, $sSecretBASE64Decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
```

But the decoded value($sSecretDecoded) differs from the original value got from C# program. I'm unable to add cIV value to my php 3des decrypt.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!